# How can i reload the data in jquery data table on button click?

Tags: jquery

Onbutton click I trigger the ajax.reload method which is given below:

and I get the attached error.

```
$("#btnGenerate").on("click", function (event) {

            $('#tblDataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload({ url: "/Home/GetStatus", type: "GET", datatype: "json" })
        });
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[The documentation for `ajax.reload()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload()) says it expects a function and a bool.  Just as the error states, this is indeed not a function:

```
{ url: "/Home/GetStatus", type: "GET", datatype: "json" }
```

The options for *how* to get the data from AJAX are in the initialization of the DataTables plugin.  All you need to do here is reload it:

```
$('#tblDataTable').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Ideally when you initialize the plugin you store the table in a variable:

```
let myTable = $('#tblDataTable').DataTable({
    // your initialization options
});
```

Then you can use the variable to easily reload:

```
myTable.ajax.reload();
```

That way you don't have to invoke the jQuery selector again, invoke the plugin again, etc.